# Pytest Xdist parallel execution, prevent recreating the database

Tags: selenium, pytest, xdist, pytest-xdist

I'm trying to speed up the Selenium tests in my python Django web application by using parallel execution of 4 threads (-n=4)

Of the first 4 tests, 3 give the following error:

```
[test setup] [Test Error Output]
Got an error creating the test database: (1007, "Can't create database 'test1database'; database exists")
```

I get that I have to specify setup to be run once before parallel test execution, to prevent this multiple attempts at creating the database, but how would I enforce this in pytest xdist configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably have a different database for each one of the threads. The `worker_id` fixture allows you to do that
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist#identifying-the-worker-process-during-a-test

```
@pytest.fixture()
def test_database(worker_id):
    return CreateDatabase("test{}database".format(worker_id))
```

**Update**

This [github issue comment](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/issues/271#issuecomment-385594404) shows a solution to the OP's original problem. It also creates N databases, using a shared template. This brings the interesting twist of synchronizing the access to a shared resource in fixture.

Comment: I prefer to use env variabke for worker id - PYTEST_XDIST_WORKER: the name of the worker eg "gw2"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you won't be stuck in any problem in the rest of your code:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test1database;
```